# Swift UIColor initializer - compiler error only when targeting iPhone5s

Tags: ios, swift

## The Situation:

**Working from a new project:** iOS > Application > Game > SpriteKit, Swift, iPhone

Here I've written a function in my `GameScene.swift` to accept a hex color value and alpha double.  I am going by the Swift documentation, and referencing an elegant solution I saw online.  I've noticed this exact code compiles, runs and displays the proper color for a build target of **iPhone5** in the simulator.

## But...

The exact same project wont even compile when my build target is set for **iPhone5s**.

[image: the compiler error]

> Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments.

The function:

```
// colorize function takes HEX and Alpha converts then returns aUIColor object
func colorize (hex: Int, alpha: Double = 1.0) -> UIColor {
    let red = Double((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
    let green = Double((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0
    let blue = Double((hex & 0xFF)) / 255.0
    var color: UIColor = UIColor( red: Float(red), green: Float(green), blue: Float(blue), alpha:Float(alpha) )
    return color
}
```

The related call in `didMoveToView`:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    // blue background color
    self.backgroundColor = colorize( 0x003342, alpha:1.0)

}
```

Admittedly I am very new to iOS development, but I am wondering what is going on to cause the compiler not to find this initializer?

*EDIT: putting up a github momentarily*

[A quick gist with related files... the only one I've edited is GameScene.swift](https://gist.github.com/josephjaniga/91a9f54e7208ac83a2e7)

Comment: Perhaps this is a bug.  This looks almost exactly like an example from the documentation. http://i.imgur.com/bHKL7Yg.png

Comment: does it error on both 32 and 64 bit simulators?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It probably has to do with a mismatch between Float and Double. Basically, if the arguments are expected to be CGFloats, you need to pass CGFloats.

```
let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
```

What's important to understand here is that CGFloat is defined as Float on 32 bit platforms, and Double on 64 bit platforms. So, if you're explicitly using Floats, Swift won't have a problem with this on 32 Bit platforms, but will produce an error on 64 bit.

Comment: Interesting that Swift has an issue with this.  Objective-C wouldn't have a problem if you sent a float as the argument to this method on a 64-bit or a double as the argument on a 32-bit, would it?

Comment: @nhgrif It would not. But then again, Objective-C didn't take issue with the word "implicit" quite like Swift does.

Answer (score 10):

See from the source code you should use CGFloat instead of Float

[image]

this should work

```
func colorize (hex: Int, alpha: Double = 1.0) -> UIColor {
    let red = Double((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
    let green = Double((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0
    let blue = Double((hex & 0xFF)) / 255.0
    var color: UIColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha:CGFloat(alpha) )
    return color
}
```