# arc4random and arm64 with swift

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift, xcode6

I am trying to make a function in sprite kit that generates a random color. Here is the code I use:

```
var hue = Float(arc4random() % 256) / 256.0;
var saturation = Float(arc4random() % 128) / 256.0 + 0.5;
var brightness = Float(arc4random() % 128) / 256.0 + 0.5;
self.color = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1);
```

The last line, when compiling to iPad Air and iPhone 5S, throws this error:

```
Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

I'm sure it has something to do with arc4random() on arm64 generating something that it doesn't like. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24196575/2446155

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters for `UIColor(hue: saturation: brightness: alpha)` are all of type `CGFloat`. The problem you're seeing is that `CGFloat` is aliased to different types depending on the architecture. For 32-bit ARM, (iPhone 4S and 5), it's a `Float` internally, but for arm64, it's actually a `Double`. If you just use `CGFloat` instead of `Float` for your type casts it will work fine:

```
var hue = CGFloat(arc4random() % 256) / 256.0;
var saturation = CGFloat(arc4random() % 128) / 256.0 + 0.5;
var brightness = CGFloat(arc4random() % 128) / 256.0 + 0.5;
self.color = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1);
```