# UIColor extension in Swift error

Tags: swift, uicolor

I have this extension:

```
extension UIColor {
    func rgba(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int, a: Float) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: a)
    }    
}
```

This is giving me an error message: `Extra argument 'green' in call`

I dont get why this is happening, might be a bug in xcode 6 beta 4 or in swift.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift UIColor initializer - compiler Error only when targeting iPhone5s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196528/swift-uicolor-initializer-compiler-error-only-when-targeting-iphone5s) - (All arguments must be converted to CGFloat.)

Comment: Better get a good book on the "C" language and learn how integer arithmetic works.

Comment: `r/255.0 g/255.0 b/255.0`

Comment: @MartinR I have already tried that, no use. Thanks for the downvote though

Comment: @MartinR And I do not get the same error as the question you have linked either.

Comment: @Arbitur: I think it is the same  issue: you have to convert the integers to CGFloat explicitly. The Swift error messages can still be misleading or changing between releases. (Btw. I did not downvote your question.)

Comment: As an aside, shouldn't that be a class function, rather than requiring an existing instance of a colour?

Comment: In my case the problem was that I declared the function prototype w/o `-> UIColor`

Answer (score 8):

It is because you passed all the parameters with wrong type: `r/255, g/255, b/255` are Integer and `a` is Float, but the UIColor's init method accepts CGFloat for the 4 parameters.

Modify the code to:

```
func rgba(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int, a: Float) -> UIColor {
    let floatRed = CGFloat(r) / 255.0
    let floatGreen = CGFloat(g) / 255.0
    let floatBlue = CGFloat(b) / 255.0
    return UIColor(red: floatRed, green: floatGreen, blue: floatBlue, alpha: CGFloat(a))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(r: Int, g:Int , b:Int , a: Int) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/255, green: CGFloat(g)/255, blue: CGFloat(b)/255, alpha: CGFloat(a)/255)
    }
}
let myColor = UIColor(r: 255 , g: 255, b: 255, a: 255)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
extension UIColor {
    class func rgba(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int, a: Float) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: a)
    }     
}
```