# Could not find an overload for '/' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, operator-overloading, var

Could not find an overload for '/' that accepts the supplied arguments for following statement.

```
class func getColor(hexColor:NSString) -> UIColor
{
    var red, green, blue:CUnsignedInt
    var range : NSRange
    range.length = 2
    range.location = 0
    NSScanner.scannerWithString(hexColor.substringWithRange(range)).scanHexInt(&red)
    range.location = 2
    NSScanner.scannerWithString(hexColor.substringWithRange(range)).scanHexInt(&green)
    range.location = 4
    NSScanner.scannerWithString(hexColor.substringWithRange(range)).scanHexInt(&blue)
    red = Float(red/255.0)
    green = Float(green/255.0)
    blue = Float(blue/255.0)
    return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    //return UIColor(red: Float(red/255.0), green: Float(green/255.0), blue: Float(blue/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    //return UIColor.cyanColor()
}
```

What's going wrong? 
How to use division(/) in swift? 
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094184/uicolor-extension-in-swift-error.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R. But I can't find solution from that. I try this way of assigning var, but not working in my case.

Comment: From the answer to above link: `let floatRed = CGFloat(red) / 255.0`.

Comment: Have a look at the above link again. You cannot use the same variable `red` for an integer and a float.