# Extra argument in call when using var

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use this code:

```
var alpha : Float
alpha = 0.5
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green:0, blue: 0, alpha:alpha)
```

However, I get the error:

> Extra argument 'green' in call

What is wrong with this code? Moreover, why is

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green:0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
```

working just fine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift UIColor initializer - compiler Error only when targeting iPhone5s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196528/swift-uicolor-initializer-compiler-error-only-when-targeting-iphone5s)

Comment: "Moreover, why is [...] working just fine ?" because `alpha` is `Float`, not `CGFloat` (see the duplicate).

Comment: Ha, I didn't found this answer ! Thanks:) ... The error message wasn't so helpful :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer was: [Swift UIColor initializer - compiler error only when targeting iPhone5s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196528/swift-uicolor-initializer-compiler-error-only-when-targeting-iphone5s)

Use float instead of integers.

```
UIColor(red: 1.0, green:0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha:alpha)
```

Comment: It's all about the parameters and primitive types.

Answer (score 2):

This also happens when you unwrap the a `UIColor` instance that wasn't declared as optional.

Instead of:

```
let brokenColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)!
```

Use this:

```
let color: UIColor! = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using variables use following -

```
var color: UIColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
```

Answer (score 0):

My particular iteration of this error happened when I was trying to set the border color of a button, and was getting the "extra argument 'green' in call" error, but once I stored it in a constant the true error arose, which was the constant not being  CGColor. So this fixed it.

```
  let borderColor:UIColor = UIColor(red: 23/255, green: 247/255, blue: 252/255, alpha: 1)
  loginButton.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
```

Answer (score -6):

Put a space after the semicolons in the call

```
green: 0, alpha: alpha
```